# blazor-client-side is synonymous with blazor-webassembly

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

Microsoft's [Blazor](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet/web-apps/blazor) which allows building rich and interactive web apps offers [two hosting models](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hosting-models?view=aspnetcore-5.0):

- Blazor server-side (uses SignalR, C# code runs on the server) ​
- Blazor WebAssembly (WASM)  (C# runs in WebAssembly on the client's browser)

From the [description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blazor-webassembly) of the [blazor-webassembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blazor-webassembly) tag:

> Use this tag for questions specific to client-side hosted Blazor apps.

Technically, when client-side Blazor is referred to, it usually refers to Blazor WebAssembly and hence the tag [blazor-client-side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blazor-client-side) is <s>ambiguous to</s> synonymous with [blazor-webassembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blazor-webassembly) and redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a bit of a misunderstanding of words here:

- "Ambiguous" means that a tag has multiple meanings, which can't be easily gleaned just by looking at the tag; a reader has to look at the question to understand what it means in context.
- Based on what you said, [blazor-client-side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blazor-client-side) is *not* ambiguous to, but rather, *synonymous with*, [blazor-webassembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blazor-webassembly).
- Our tags can be made synonyms with other tags that refer to the same thing; burnination of the other tags isn't necessary in such a case.

Somebody has already proposed [blazor-client-side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blazor-client-side) as a synonym of [blazor-webassembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blazor-webassembly), and most questions with either of these two tags already have *both* tags anyway, so I've gone ahead and approved their proposal.